# <img> tag cannot be nested in <a> tag

Tags: visual-studio, html, image

what is the reason that `<img>` tag cannot be nested in `<a>` tag by HTML5 specifications

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="src" alt="alt"/>
</a>
```

visual studio 2010 sp1 say that

[image]

Comment: ummm, can you give a reference as to where it says this? Never heard of this before now.

Comment: @JohnP did you use visual studio ever? if not this question is not referenced you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896118/visual-studio-html5-validation-element-img-cannot-be-nested-within-element-a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is allowed, but not necessarily in every situation.

An `a` element's content model is [*transparent*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#transparent), which means, its content model is the same as its parent's content model.

Respective [`a` specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element):

> **Content model:**
>   [Transparent](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#transparent), but there must be no interactive content descendant.

Respective [`img` specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-img-element):

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>   Where [embedded content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedded-content) is expected.

So if the content model of the `a` element's parent is *phrasing content* or *embedded content*, the `img` element is allowed:

> As a general rule, elements whose content model allows any phrasing content should have either at least one descendant text node that is not inter-element whitespace, or at least one descendant element node that is embedded content.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a valid construction. Are you perhaps using Visual Studio which is telling you this? Because it's a bug in the web standards of Visual Studio.

Get the web standards update here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is incorrect; this is a perfectly valid construction.